# Not a Class - TypeError: function() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've already read several postingss on Stackoverflow about this error and the questions related to it: so this function is not a class method, there's not duplicated in the script, etc. It's a tkinter even-driven function. I saw a similar one on another posting, I tried it and it worked, but mine doesn't, and I can't figure why.
If you have nothing helpful to say, please refrain from making wise remarks, otherwise thanks in advance for the help.

For clarity, I reduced the context to its bare bones:

```
from tkinter import *

w = Tk()

def initializeVars():
    global extRequired, Keyword, filePath
##    extRequired = text1.get()
##    Keyword = text2.get()
##    filePath=BaseDir+AllFiles
    print('initializing variables')

def func(event):
    print("You hit return.")
w.bind('<Return>',initializeVars)

# Buttons
Button(text='Select Folder', command=initializeVars).grid(row=10,column=2)

w.mainloop()
```

As you can see I'm trying to bind `initializeVars` function to the **return key** of the keybaord.

Comment: This should solve your problem, yes? [TypeError: printName1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given](//stackoverflow.com/q/33427263)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
w.bind('<Return>', initializeVars)
```

Event bindings expect a function that takes an `event` argument as the first parameter. So while you use the `initializeVars` correctly as a button handler, you need to accept the `event` parameter for the `bind` to work.

If you don’t *need* the event, you can also make it optional:

```
def initializeVars(event = None):
    # ...
    print('initializing variables')
```

Comment: thank you much for the very useful help.